# How to install libdata-validate-ip-perl in centos

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to use IP in my perl script and i got module not found error. When i tried to install it with dnf im getting no match found for the package.

```
use Data::Validate::IP;
```

> Can't locate Data/Validate/IP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
> Data::Validate::IP module) (@INC contains: ../utils
> /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
> /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
> /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at ../utils/VM.pm line 5. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at ../utils/VM.pm line 5. Compilation
> failed in require at ./myscript.pl line 37.

```
#dnf install libdata-validate-ip-perl

Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - Epel (Intel mirror)                                                                                                          5.6 kB/s | 4.7 kB     00:00
Last metadata expiration check: -1596 days, 2:25:26 ago on Wed 09 Nov 2022 09:59:43 AM IST.
No match for argument: libdata-validate-ip-perl
Error: Unable to find a match: libdata-validate-ip-perl
```

Looking for suggestions to install perl missing modules

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
sudo cpan Data::Validate::IP
```

See here https://perldoc.perl.org/cpan

Answer (score 1):

"libdata-validate-ip-perl" would be the name of the package on Debian-based distributions, such as Ubuntu.

Redhat-based distributions use a different naming convention for their packages. Try "perl-Data-Validate-IP".